# How to pull pull all repositories with single click?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I use Eclipse and EGit.

I have a lot of repositories (around 40) which need a pull every day, sometimes even more often.

I am looking for a way to either automate this on eclipse startup or manually pull with a single click "pull all" button.

(I know I can select multiple projects in the explorer and go to *Team > Pull*, but I hope for a better way.)

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view you can create a so-called _Repository Group_. With a configured shortcut key for the _Pull_ command, you only have to select the group and hit the configured key to do a pull in all grouped repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this in the *Git Repositories* view.

1. Select all repos.
2. Right-click.
3. Select *Pull*.

I don't know if this is easier than your current work-flow.

Tip 1: You can organize your repos using *Repository Groups* in the *Git Repositories* view.

Tip 2 (thanks to Howlger): You can add a keyboard shortcut for the *Pull* command in order to make it even more convenient to use.